# How do i use runhaskell with cabal-dev?

Tags: haskell, cabal, runhaskell

Unfortunately cabal-dev ghci does not work in this project, i get an error:

```
Loading package download-0.3.2 ... linking ... 
ghc: /home/stulli/haskell/ifdl/cabal-dev//lib/download-0.3.2/ghc-7.4.1/HSdownload-0.3.2.o: unknown symbol `stat64'
ghc: unable to load package `download-0.3.2'
```

So i try runhaskell, but it uses the packages that come installed with cabal instead of cabal-dev and thus fails.

update:
runhaskell produces the same error:

```
$ runhaskell -isrc:src/test -package-conf=cabal-dev/packages-7.4.1.conf src/test/Test.hs
Test.hs: /home/stulli/haskell/ifdl/cabal-dev//lib/download-0.3.2/ghc-7.4.1/HSdownload-0.3.2.o: unknown symbol `stat64'
Test.hs: Test.hs: unable to load package `download-0.3.2'
```

cabal-dev install on the other hand works without problems.

Comment: If you use `cabal sandbox` (which didn't exist when you asked the question), you can just do `cabal exec runhaskell main.hs`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try something like the next:

```
runhaskell -package-conf=cabal-dev/packages-7.0.3.conf main.hs
```

But I think if `cabal-dev ghci` doesn't work, then `runhaskell` will not work too. You need to find out what is wrong with `download` package.

Comment: Yes, you were right. runhaskell had the same mistake.
cabal-dev install works though...

Comment: Since this worked on another directory (without corrupted packages) i'll accept this answer.

Comment: in GHC 7.6 `-package-conf` is deprecated `-package-db` should be used instead, see http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.1/html/users_guide/packages.html#package-databases

Answer (score 10):

To use `runhaskell` with cabal sandboxes (cabal >= 1.18), run the command

```
runhaskell -package-db=.cabal-sandbox/i386-windows-ghc-7.6.3-packages.conf.d <file.hs>
```

substituting the proper `*-packages.conf.d` directory for your GHC version.

Answer (score 1):

The `cabal-dev` setup doesn't work very well for `ghci`, so it might very well be that it also doesn't work well for `runhaskell`. Maybe [virthualenv](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/virthualenv) will work better for this use case?

Comment: For now i get an error because of a base dependency error when installing virthualenv. I'll try it when i'm in the mood for fiddling around a bit more, so thanks for the hint. Maybe i'll look for an alternative for the download package which i can use in the future.