# Problems with Test-Framework and HUnit

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, cabal, hunit

I have problems setting up unit-tests with Test-Framework and HUnit.
I have the following imports in my testfile:

```
import Test.Framework
import Test.Framework.Providers.QuickCheck2
import Test.Framework.Providers.HUnit
```

When I try to load the file in `ghci` I get the error-message:

```
test/MainTestSuite.hs:3:8:
    Could not find module ‘Test.Framework.Providers.HUnit’
    Perhaps you meant
      Test.Framework.Providers.API (from test-framework-0.8.1.1)
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Only loading `Test.Framework` and `Test.Framework.Providers.QuickCheck2` works and can run the tests. According to `cabal` `test-framework-hunit`
is installed:

```
$ cabal install test-framework-hunit
Resolving dependencies...
All the requested packages are already installed:
test-framework-hunit-0.3.0.1
Use --reinstall if you want to reinstall anyway.
Notice: installing into a sandbox located at
/home/XXX/projects/my_project/.cabal-sandbox
```

Also `test-framework-hunit` is listed as a dependency in the `my_project.cabal`-file:

```
test-suite tests
    main-is:           
        MainTestSuite.hs
    type:              
    exitcode-stdio-1.0
    hs-source-dirs:    
        test, 
        src
    build-depends:     
        base,
        HUnit,
        QuickCheck,
        test-framework,
        test-framework-hunit,
        test-framework-quickcheck2,
        containers >=0.5 && <0.6
    default-language:
        Haskell2010
```

What am I doing wrong? If that matters: I'm installing everything into a `cabal-sandbox`.

Comment: How are you running `ghci`? Did you pass it the [`-package-db` flag](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24840899/414413) to tell `ghci` where to find the sandbox installed packages?

Comment: No this was the problem ... i wasn't aware that ghci is not aware of sandboxes by default.

Answer (score 0):

Sandboxed packages are visible to `cabal` but not to `ghc` or `ghci` without additional flags. But you can alter your environment in general for a process by executing it with `cabal exec myCmd` -- and even better, for `ghci` in particular, `cabal repl` is a more full-featured solution that opens "stuff you want" in a variety of situations, both with and without sandboxes.